# Observable - filter and toggle property (angular)

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, toggle

I'm filtering an observable of an array of objects with an observable of a form control in angular.

This is working fine, but I now want to toggle a property on every object in the array to expand or collapse it in the list, and this is where i'm stuck..

I thought of two options:

Option 1
Use a BehaviorSubject so I can access the current value then I can iterate over the list when the button is clicked and toggle the property

Option 2
I'm using combineLatest for the filtering so could I add an observable of the button click (so I combine three observables) and somehow toggle the properties there?

Either option i'm not exactly sure how to do..

Here is a simple stackblitz example with what i'm trying to achieve. So I want hook up the Toggle All Lists button so it toggles the "expanded" property on all the objects in the array

https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-toggle-observable

Edit:

I managed to get it working with a BehaviorSubject. See new stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-toggle-observable2

The last thing I would like to achieve is to filter the tasks within the lists too. I've tried in the stackblitz (currently commented out) but I think my method is mutable so when the filter input is removed the tasks are still filtered? How can I fix it so that when the filter input is removed the tasks are again unfiltered and therefore are displayed?

Edit 2:

I've managed to get it working but it would be great to have someone check my working and see if there is a simpler way of doing this. It seemed quite convoluted to do what appeared quite simple..

My requirements were:

- tasks must be grouped and listed under entities (entities could have no tasks but the entity should still be displayed)
- when user inputs a filter both the tasks and entities should be filtered (if entity contains a task that matches the filter it should still be displayed)
- the toggle button should toggle the expanded state of all entities

I found the grouping and filtering quite straightforward but the toggle was difficult. I could have added it to combineLatest but then I would be doing the grouping and filtering when all was needed was to toggle a property on each element..

Here's my stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-toggle-observable4

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but you can do it this way:

```
<input matInput [formControl]="filter">

<div *ngFor="let list of (filteredLists$ | async) as filteredArray; index as i">
  <button *ngIf="i==0" (click)="toggleAllLists(filteredArray)">Toggle All Lists</button>
  <div class="list">
    <button class="material-icons list-toggle" (click)="toggleListExpand(list)">
      chevron_right
    </button>
    {{list.name}}
    <div *ngFor="let task of list.tasks" class="task"
    [style.max-height.px]="list.expanded ? list.tasks.length*30 : 0">
    {{task.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically declare your Observable + async pipe as another template var "filteredArray". Now inside the main div you have your array.

Then you move the toggle all button inside the main div and using ngIf prevent it duplicating itself N times, only allowing it to exist at the top of the list.

Now inside your ts add the method:

```
toggleAllLists(lists) {
    lists.forEach(list => {
      list.expanded = !list.expanded
    })
  }
```

You probably may need to define new property to track expanded or not depending on your UX, cause the above code just toggles whatever state lists are in.

Here is stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-toggle-observable-6gu3sq

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example, thats a good technique to know. I managed to find a solution with the BehaviorSubject method (see the edit to my question). The last thing I would like to do is filter the tasks too (also see my edit). Do you know how I can achieve that?